# Wpf webbrowser rendering issues

Tags: c#, wpf, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I have a wpf page with a Web Browser in a grid :

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <WebBrowser Name="browser" Margin="0" Grid.Row="2"/>
</Grid>
```

The page I try to display looks like (on IE, Chrome, Edge):
[image: IE]

And in my application :

[image: In application]

The table I want to display is quite straight forward :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed"><thead><tr><th><span class="h4">Ranking</span></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class="active">
            <td>25617</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>10000</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>7877</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>6000</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>5750</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>5000</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>2501</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>1758</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>31</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>22</td>
        </tr></tbody></table>
```

I used this code to use the best IE installed :

```
   public static bool SetBrowserEmulationVersion()
    {
        int ieVersion;
        BrowserEmulationVersion emulationCode;

        ieVersion = GetInternetExplorerMajorVersion();

        if (ieVersion >= 11)
        {
            emulationCode = BrowserEmulationVersion.Version11;
        }
        else
        {
            switch (ieVersion)
            {
                case 10:
                    emulationCode = BrowserEmulationVersion.Version10;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    emulationCode = BrowserEmulationVersion.Version9;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    emulationCode = BrowserEmulationVersion.Version8;
                    break;
                default:
                    emulationCode = BrowserEmulationVersion.Version7;
                    break;
            }
        }

        return SetBrowserEmulationVersion(emulationCode);
    }
```

code found here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/793687/Configuring-the-emulation-mode-of-an-Internet-Expl

I've worked in several cases with web browser and it has always worked fine. This is the first time I want to display a table.

Do you know why the red is missing in my application ?
And why there is a vertical scrollbar displayed ?

Comment: Please add table css, could be usefull to make some tests